# Cant connect to eth0 after wlan0 sharing with iptables

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

I wanted my Ubuntu server to act as a wifi hotspot.  So I set up hostapd to allow wifi connections.  I then setup dnsmasq to provide the DHCP settings.

I then added the following iptables rules, so wifi data will be passed through to eth0

```
 /sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

As far as Wifi clients are concerned this is working perfectly.  However, this has had the unexpected (to me anyway) consequence of stopping me connecting to the IP address assigned to eth0 (from my second computer on the wired network).

The eth0 IP address/netmask hasn't changed with this config, and I can (somehow) still connect to it using my internet IP via the port forwarding on the router.

Any ideas on what I need to do to restore connectivity to eth0?

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the solution to this.

I had eth0 as 192.168.0.11 and wlan0 as 192.168.0.200 both with a subnet of 255.255.255.0.

I changed the wlan0 to 192.168.1.1 and 255.255.0.0, then updated hostapd and dnsmasq so they would allocate in the 102.168.1.0 range.

I can now connect to eth0 and wifi clients still have access to the network.